# How to determine if event was fired from scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have a div in which I have implemented iPad like swiping.

Check out what I mean on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4KP9/) (Just click and drag your mouse in the div.)

I want to prevent the swiping from happening when someone is using the scroll bar (click on the scrollbar, then move from left to right, swiping still occurs).

In short, what I need is if(!event.wasTriggeredFromScrollbar) that I can use in any event trigger (in this case mousedown/move/up).

jQuery and regular 'ol Javascript answers welcomed.

Edited: To make a lot more sense.

Comment: Did you try to know the position the user has clicked/tapped and check against the position of the scrollbars? Not easy though.

Comment: @muistooshort Not exactly, it's up on JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/k4KP9/)

Comment: `<div class=".panel" ` is not correct. The class 'panel' will have the selector '.panel'. the '.' indicates it's a class name and not.. say an id (#) ... so you want `<div class="panel"` for the selector `.panel`

Comment: @rlemon That was just a quick typing error, my bad. In all of my real scripts I'm using it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I got around this, as it doesn't seem to actually be possible.

**Step 1:** Capture the **MouseDown** event. Store the current position of scrollLeft and scrollTop into variables.

**Step 2:** On the **MouseMove** event, check the current position of *scrollLeft* and *scrollTop* and compare them against your variables. If they're different, then cancel whatever operation you were going to perform. If they're the same, the *MouseDown* event wasn't triggered by a scrollbar (or anything else that would change scrollLeft and scrollTop such as another animation), and you're free to do what you wish!

Happy coding!

Comment: Just a note that scrollLeft and scrollTop are properties of the actual element, not the event.